# How to change Script-scoped variable with function in powershell?

Tags: powershell, variables, scopes

Have the script

```
[int] $num01 = 2

function setNo ([int] $num02)
{
    $num01 = $num02;
}

write-host $num01

setNo -num02 4

write-host $num01

setNo -num02 6

write-host $num01
```

It produces an output

```
2
2
2
```

How to make it produce output:

```
2
4
6
```

Comment: You would need to use a scope modifier for this, `$script:num01 = $num02`, however it is very likely that there is a better and cleaner way of doing this if you explain what you're trying to accomplish or why it is required that you update a variable outside the function's scope.

Comment: Santiago Squarzon thanks, that's what i needed!
Originally there's a big script and a function sets its parameters depending on how it 's launched

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways of altering the value of a variable outside the function's scope, for example:

- By [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref?view=powershell-7.2):

```
([ref] $num01).Value = $num02;
```

- Using a [Scope Modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2#scope-modifiers):

```
$script:num01 = $num02;
```

- Using [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable?view=powershell-7.2#:%7E:text=The%20Set%2DVariable%20cmdlet%20assigns,exist%2C%20the%20cmdlet%20creates%20it.) with the `-Scope Script` argument or `$ExecutionContext`:

```
Set-Variable num01 -Value $num02 -Scope Script
# OR
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.PSVariable.Set('script:num01', $num02)
```

Note that, in this particular case, one of the above is necessary because the outside variable `$num01` is a *scalar*, it would not be the case if it was a *non-scalar*, i.e. an array or hash table:

```
$num01 = @(2) # => array of a single element, index 0

function setNo ([int] $num02) {
    $num01[0] = $num02 # => updating index 0 of the array
}

setNo 10; $num01 # => 10
```

Answer (score 0):

it's
$script:num01 = $num02

as Santiago Squarzon wrote in comments.